# Is there a way to make gitlab runnder produce a verbose output on deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci

Here is my job from .gitlab-ci.yml

```
deploy:
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy aws-base:latest # see the note below
  script:
    - aws s3 ...
    - aws create-deployment ...
  only:
    - master
```

the deployment process fails with
ERROR: Preparation failed: invalid reference format (docker.go:198:0s)

trace variable has no effect on output.

The build process still fails. Here are the new logs:

```
 ++ export CI_DEBUG_TRACE=true
 ++ CI_DEBUG_TRACE=true
 ++ export CI_DISPOSABLE_ENVIRONMENT=true
 ++ CI_DISPOSABLE_ENVIRONMENT=true
 ++ export CI_RUNNER_VERSION=13.0.0
 ++ CI_RUNNER_VERSION=13.0.0
 ++ export CI_RUNNER_REVISION=c127439c
 ++ CI_RUNNER_REVISION=c127439c
 ++ export CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH=linux/amd64
 ++ CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH=linux/amd64
 ++ cd /builds/Zyubenko/humans
 + exit 0
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between the repository URL and the image tag.

```
deploy:
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest # see the note below
  script:
    - aws s3 ...
    - aws create-deployment ...
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped, but the build process still fails. See my answer above for logs.